# Why doesn't my preg_match work?

Tags: php, regex, debugging

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['account']))
{
    $str = $_POST[account];
    if ( !preg_match( "^[0-9]+$", $str ))
    {
        print "<p class=\"fadeout\" style=\"color:rgba(240, 240, 0, 1.0);\" >Enter numbers only!</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        exec('"cmd /c echo weee!"');
        print "<p class=\"fadeout\" style=\"color:rgba(240, 240, 0, 1.0);\" >Your account has been added.</p>";
    }
}
else {
    if (isset($_POST['account']) || $account == "") {
        print "<form method=\"post\"><p>Enter your account number below.</p>";
        print "<input name=\"account\" type=\"text\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"7\"><input value=\"Send\" type=\"submit\"></form>";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to get input from visitors with their account number, then I want PHP to verify if it is a number inputted and do some action.

Right now, it shows the input box and button, but hitting the submit button causes it to show "Enter numbers only!" regardless of what they enter.

Why isn't it properly detecting the numbers?

Comment: You should enable warnings in your code with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. You'll then get an error message from the incorrectly formatted regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your regex is not right. Try this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $str))
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like a simple syntax error around your post input.

```
if (isset($_POST['account']))
            {
                $str = $_POST[account];
```

should be changed to

```
if (isset($_POST['account']))
            {
                $str = $_POST['account'];
```

Comment: PHP will automatically convert unquoted identifiers to strings if they're not the name of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You aren't getting the value from the `$_POST` properly.

Incorrect:
    `$str = $_POST[account];`

Correct:
    `$str = $_POST['account'];`

2. Your regular expression is wrong.

You can test regular expressions here:  https://regex101.com/

If you want it to JUST accept numbers, then change this line:

```
if ( ! preg_match( "^[0-9]+$", $str ))
```

To this:

```
if ( ! preg_match( "(^[0-9]+$)", $str))
```

Answer (score 0):

1 please do research by yourself, check your code by yourself or run it by yourself and check the error log

`$account`

has not been set in this script and

`isset($_POST['account'])`

is already false because it is already in a false statement after a check if it was true and you can use ifelse or a switch statement

[ifelse](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

[switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)